# I want to react on a message in discord and then it should send a embed in discord.py

Tags: python, encoding, discord, bots

```
if message.content.startswith('/overview'):
    embed = discord.Embed(title='**Overview**', description='This is a Overview for the Service! (easier then the manual methode)', color=16769251)
    embed.add_field(name='Create an Offer:', value='React on ✉️ to Create an own Offer')
    mess = await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
    await mess.add_reaction('✉️')
```

I used this to send an embed with `✉️` as reaction.

Now I want that if you react a new embed gets sent by the bot in the same channel.

Comment: What exactly was the problem when you tried to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the event [`discord.on_raw_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=react#discord.RawReactionActionEvent) which will be called when a reaction gets added to the message, here's an example:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.emoji.name == "✉️" and payload.user_id != client.user.id:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            description = "This embed was sent because you have reacted with ✉️ ",
            colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(0, 255, 0)
        )
        channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: if u look in my script:
when u use /overview it automatily reacts on the message. then it sends the embed message
but i want that the embed gets not send if the author is the bot :D please ;D

Comment: I've edited the answer which will stop sending an embed if the bot reacts to the message.

Comment: File "c:\Users\jonas\Desktop\Service Bot own\Service_Bot.py", line 214
    if payload.emoji.name == "✉️" payload.user_id != client.user.id:

this is the error

Comment: Try now, it was a typo mistake from me :)

Comment: No problem, be sure to mark the answer as the solution if it helped :)